# How do I get query string arguments into a named location?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

I'm moving a PHP app from Apache2 to Nginx. The app uses the slugs in the URL, and turns them into query string arguments before passing them on to a single index.php file. After reading the Nginx manual, buying and reading an Nginx book, searching google and 3 days of hacking at it, I still can't figure out how to get what should be a simple rule set working.

This is the config I've come up with:

```
# If request is for the homepage, skip all rules and just serve it.
location = / {      
   try_files /cache/index.html @Cart;
}


location / {

   # Block direct access to files people don't need access to.
   location ^~ /.php{ internal; }
   location ~ /\.ht { deny all; }

   #Attempt to match Slugs
   location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$ {
      try_files /cache/$1.html @Cart; // Help: need to pass $1 to index.php?rt=$1
   }

   location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/$ {
      try_files /cache/$1-$2.html @Cart; // Help: need to pass $1 and $2 to index.php?rt=$1&action=$2
   }
}

# Pass the PHP script to Cart
location @Cart {
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

The problem is how to do get to the named location with the query string parameters that are needed. Putting the index.php file in try_files causes the contents of the file to be output to the browser as plain text, even with an index.php location that has a `fastcgi_pass` directive. I could use rewrite, but I've been unable to figure out how to do a rewrite and pass to a named location.

Requests other than the home page `/` should execute `/index.php?rt=$1&action=$2` if te cache doesn't exist, where $1 and $2 are the URL slugs. How can I pass those arguments into the named location?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass arguments. You could get them in `@Cart` location.

```
location @Cart {
   rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)/$ /index.php?rt=$1&action=$2 break;
   rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /index.php?rt=$1 break;

   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Here I used simple regexp because of previous `location`s that "filtered" uri.